# Почему heredoc работает?

Tags: php, php7, синтаксис

В документации сказано, что отступы перед закрывающем тегом heredoc недопустим, так почему здесь работает? Если есть вложенность, то heredoc может иметь отступ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В документации это не отмечено, но так можно с PHP7.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration73.new-features.php#migration73.new-features.core.heredoc

написано:

**Более гибкий синтаксис Heredoc и Nowdoc**

> После закрывающего идентификатора в doc-строках больше не нужно
> ставить точку с запятой или новую строку. Кроме того, **закрывающий
> идентификатор может быть с отступом**, и в этом случае он будет удалён
> из всех строк в doc-строке.

Жаль, что об этом не написано в самом описании heredoc https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc